# Android PlacesAutoCompleteFragment trigger onPlaceSelected

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I'm using PlacesAutoCompleteFragment and added to it a PlaceSelectionListener.
It works fine when the user is actually clicks on some place and 
the method onPlaceSelected is triggered.

But I have some cases when I need to programatically set a text in the places search bar and then to trigger the onPlaceSelected method.

I used the method setText to enter the text programatically but the onPlaceSelected is not triggered. is there any way to trigger it programatically?

```
PlacesAutocompleteFragment autocompletePlacesFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
{
    ....
    autocompletePlaceFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.places_frament);
    placesFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener()
    {
         @Override
         public void onPlaceSelected(Place place)
         {
              Log.d("TAG","onPlaceSelected");
         }

         @Override
         public void onError(Status status)
         {
              Log.d("TAG", "onError");
         }
    });

     //Now when I use this method, I want to trigger onPlaceSelected..
     autocompletePlaceFragment.setText("Washington");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after I checked for a while how to get a `Place` using a string, the 
answer is that for right now you can't.

Place is an Interface that GooglePlaces gives us. 
It has some methods like `getId()`, `getName()`, etc..

What I was trying to do when I have a string that contains an address, for example "Washington" is to trigger the `onPlaceSelected` method and then take the 
`latitude` and `longitude` that `Place` gives us.

You can trigger the onPlaceSelected method by creating a PlaceSelectionListener 
as your class member.

for example:

```
PlaceSelectionListener listener = new PlaceSelectionListener()
{
     @Override
     public void onPlaceSelected(Place place)
     {
         Log.d("TAG","onPlaceSelected");
     }

     @Override
     public void onError(Status status)
     {
        Log.d("TAG","onError");
     } 
};
```

after you have this listener you can use it:

```
listener.onPlaceSelected(yourPlace);
```

Notice that the method requires a Place variable as a parameter.. 
it cannot accept String, as an I said before, for now.. PlacesApi doesn't
give any method to get a Place from a string.. so you must have a valid 
Place object in order to you this method.

as for my application I found another solution and I used the Android Geocoder 
instead, it gives me the correct latitude and longitude for an address.